# Unable to add captions to shiny app table

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am creating a shiny app that involves multiple complex tables. I need to organize my work by creating captions for these tables.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
  output$table7 <- DT::renderDataTable(
datatable(table7,
          options = list(
            scrollX = TRUE,
            pageLength = -1,
            dom = 'Bfrtip',
            buttons = list('colvis')
          ),
          escape = FALSE,
          rownames = FALSE) %>%
  formatStyle(
    1,  # index of the row to format
    fontWeight = 'bold'  # set font weight to bold
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What error are you seeing? I noticed that you're missing the extensions argument which needs to be added if you're enabling buttons.

For captions you just need to include it in the function call.

```
datatable(
  table7,
  caption = HTML("<b>My caption</b>"), # Add a caption here
  extensions = 'Buttons', # include the buttons extension
  options = list(
    scrollX = TRUE,
    pageLength = -1,
    dom = 'Bfrtip',
    buttons = list('colvis')
  ),
  escape = FALSE,
  rownames = FALSE
) %>%
  formatStyle(
    1,  # index of the row to format
    fontWeight = 'bold'  # set font weight to bold
  )
```